# C# WPF XAML , How create Textbox input field with stringformat?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

Code XAML

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="Bank Doc Nbr :" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      <TextBox Name="txtBankNbr" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBankNbr, Path=Text, StringFormat={}{0:##0/000}}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="0/000" VerticalAlignment="Center" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="0" />

      <Label Content="Bank Income :€" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      <TextBox Name="txtBankIncome" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBankIncome, Path=Text,StringFormat={}{0:######0.00}}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="0,00" VerticalAlignment="Center" materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden" BorderThickness="0" />

   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

> ------ Explanation: Format of txtBankNbr is {0:##0/000} and can only receive numbers.   eg "1/001" , 12/021 , ....
>
> Format of txtBankNbr is {0:##0.00} and can only receive a decimal
> number What is wrong in my code?
>
> Thanks

Comment: Why include a <Grid> element when you don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringFormat={}{0:#.##}
```

it should show two decimal place